# Multiple Views on one screen iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, model-view-controller, uitableview

I saw mulitple apps using this, e.g. Facebook iPad App, Twitter iPad App .
How is it implemented, that multiple views can be draged in and out to the main view?
It seems as they are all in one chain of views.

I can't figured it out.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter and Facebook both do some pretty custom stuff for their iPad apps. They also both have lots of open source iOS code that helped them do it. Check out [TWUI](https://github.com/twitter/twui) from Twitter and [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) from Facebook.

A slightly easier way to do a similar effect is to use a UISplitViewController. A split view controller is kind of like the big brother of a UINavigationController on the iPhone.

Comment: UISplitViewController won't get him the sliding in and out animations, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple subview uiviews on top of each other  and move them when needed with cabasicanimation..

Also another and probably better way is using layers in quartzcore. You can addsunviews to layers and arrange them however you want. You can even make layers drop shadows and have rounded edges..